# Separation of multiple DF in many small ones

Tags: r, list, loops

I am currently facing a problem I have trouble solving and hope anyone could help me.

I have a set of different conditions with values stored in separate DFs (Condition 1, 2, 3,...).
And in each DF I have the name of Genes as row names (A,B,C,...). What I would like to do is to make one single DF for each Gene (e.g A) and include the values for all conditions in it. Like a DF for gene a with conditions 1,2,3. So that in the end I would have a list with several hundred DFs, which I would like to melt to run some tests like in the example below.

Thank you very much :)

```
Condition_1 <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100, 3,rep=TRUE)))
  row.names(Condition_1) <- c("A","B","C")

  
Condition_2 <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100, 3,rep=TRUE)))
  row.names(Condition_2) <- c("A","B","C")
  
  
  
  
  
result_A <- rbind(Condition_1[1,],
                  Condition_2[1,])

                  
result_A <- cbind(c("Condition_1", "Condition_2"),
                  result_A)     
              colnames(result_A) <- c("Condition",1:5)

              
library(reshape2)             
result_A.melted <- melt(data = result_A, 
                        variable.name = "Time",
                        value.name = "Values")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create rownames column, then bind the dataset together with `bind_rows` and split them by rownames

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
bind_rows(Condition_1 %>% 
        rownames_to_column('rn'),
          Condition_2 %>% 
       rownames_to_column('rn')) %>% 
     group_split(rn)
```

---

If there are multiple datasets with identifier names as 'Condition_' followed by some digits, then load them all at once in a `list` with `mget`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mget(ls(pattern = '^Condition_\\d+$')) %>%
     map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
               rownames_to_column('rn')) %>%
     group_split(rn)
```

Comment: Thanks both of you, thats excactly what I wanted. There is still so much to learn in programming :)

Answer (score 1):

We can get all the dataframes in a list using `mget`and bind them in one single dataframe, bring genes in a separate column instead of rownames, get the data in long format and split to have list of dataframes.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- mget(ls(pattern = 'Condition_\\d+')) %>%
            bind_rows(.id = 'condition') %>%
            tibble::rownames_to_column('Genes') %>%
            mutate(Genes = sub('\\..*', '', Genes)) %>%
            tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -c(Genes, condition)) %>%
            group_split(Genes)
result
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   Genes condition   name  value
#   <chr> <chr>       <chr> <int>
# 1 A     Condition_1 X1       88
# 2 A     Condition_1 X2       98
# 3 A     Condition_1 X3       72
# 4 A     Condition_1 X4       50
# 5 A     Condition_1 X5       80
# 6 A     Condition_2 X1       24
# 7 A     Condition_2 X2       33
# 8 A     Condition_2 X3       49
# 9 A     Condition_2 X4        2
#10 A     Condition_2 X5       67

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   Genes condition   name  value
#   <chr> <chr>       <chr> <int>
# 1 B     Condition_1 X1       73
# 2 B     Condition_1 X2       17
# 3 B     Condition_1 X3       22
#...
#...
```

Each element of `result` is a dataframe of different Genes. You can use `lapply`/`map` to iterate over each and run the tests.